# Adjusting colors map in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I am printing an image on matlab using imwrite:

```
imagesc(imageM);
imwrite(imageM, jet(N), 'fileName.jpg');
```

I can't get the same colors as those I get using imagesc on the saved figure. I tried playing with different values for N in jet (the values of the matrix imageM are between 2 and 180). However, I can't get the same result. How can I choose the range in jet to get the same colors as those using imagesc?

Answer (score 1):

You need to scale either the values in `imageM` or the colormap, because that is excatly what `imagesc`does. In your image you have 180 - 2 = 178 steps, so

```
imgmin = min(imageM(:));
imgrange = range(imageM(:));

imwrite(imageM-imgmin, jet(imgrange) , 'fileName.jpg')
```

should do the trick.

Otherwise you could go with a standard colormap with 64 entries:

```
imwrite((imageM-imgmin)*64/imgrange, jet, 'fileName.jpg')
```

Comment: what type has `imageM`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
imagesc(img)

cmap = get(gcf,'Colormap');
X = ind2rgb(img, cmap);
imwrite(X, 'out.png');
```

Comment: also look into using: `img = im2double(img, 'indexed');`

Comment: This should work as well. But again you need to scale the image values to use the full colormap.